# Looping through a set of urls in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

How would I scrape content from multiple urls using Puppeteer?

I've created a loop, but I'm only seeing the results for the first url.

I suspect it's something to do with where I declare the results variable, but I've had no luck trying, does anyone know how to do this?

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

function run() {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {

            const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
            const page = await browser.newPage();
            const urls = ["https://www.marksandspencer.com/high-neck-long-sleeve-blouse/p/p60260040?image=SD_01_T43_5168_HD_X_EC_90&color=LIGHTDENIM&prevPage=plp", "https://www.marksandspencer.com/pure-cotton-printed-short-sleeve-t-shirt/p/p60263529?image=SD_01_T41_8030Z_Z4_X_EC_90&color=WHITEMIX&prevPage=plp"];
            

              for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
                const url = urls[i];
                await page.goto(url);
                let products = await page.evaluate(() => {
                    let product = document.querySelector('h1[itemprop=name]').innerText;
                    let results = [];
                    let items = document.querySelectorAll('[data-ttip-id=sizeGridTooltip] tbody tr td label');
                    items.forEach((element) => {
                        let size = element.getAttribute('for');
                        let stockLevel = "";
                        let nearest_td = element.closest('td');
                        if (nearest_td.classList.contains('low-stock')) {
                            stockLevel = "Low stock"
                        } else if (nearest_td.classList.contains('out-of-stock')) {
                            stockLevel = "Out of stock"
                        } else {
                            stockLevel = "In stock"
                        }
                        results.push({
                            product: product,
                            size: size,
                            stock: stockLevel
                        })
                    });
                    return results
                })
                browser.close();
                return resolve(products);
            }
            
        } catch (e) {
            return reject(e);
        }
    })
}
run().then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These lines are inside your for loop:

```js
                browser.close();
                return resolve(products);
```

So as part of the first iteration, you close the browser and return the function. You should move this out of your for loop and store `products` inside an array like this:

```js
              const urls = /* ... */;
              const productsList = [];

              for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
                const url = urls[i];
                await page.goto(url);
                let products = await page.evaluate(/* ... */);
                productsList.push(products);
              }
              browser.close();
              return resolve(productsList); // resolve with an array containing the aggregated products
```

In case you are looking for a more elegant solution (for crawling the pages in parallel), you might want to have a look at the library [puppeteer-cluster](https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster) (disclaimer: I'm the author).

Comment: Ah, thanks. What do you mean store the `products` in an array? Would I do that from inside the loop? I'll take a look at puppeteer-cluster.

Comment: You need to collect the results of `page.evaluate`. I edited my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Thanks, when I do this I get `Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: results is not defined`

Comment: Can you provide your source code. I guess you did not define the variable `results`, as the message is saying.

Comment: Sure, here's the full code https://pastebin.com/La8KFDkR. This is my first time using Puppeteer, so still reading the docs and getting my head around how it works.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't see you had another variable called `results`. I tried to introduce another variable there. I edited my answer again. You don't need to change the code inside the `page.evaluate`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189276/discussion-between-als-and-thomas-dondorf).